# Cannot execute dotnet app as daemon service

Tags: shell-script, systemd, services, daemon

I'm trying to run my dotnet application as a daemon service, the first steps that I did are:

```
Created the application using NetCore 2.0
Build the binary using dotnet publish swp
```

inside Ubuntu terminal I created an user for run the daemon:

```
sudo useradd -s /sbin/nologin dotnetuser
sudo mkdir /var/swp
sudo cp -R /home/publish/* /var/swp
sudo chown -R dotnetuser:dotnetuser /var/swp
```

so I created a custom systemd unit file under: /etc/systemd/system/netcore-console-swp.service directory:

```
[Unit]
Description= Scraper SWP
DefaultDependencies = no

[Service]
Type = oneshot
RemainAfterExit = no
ExecStart= /var/bot/ swp.dll
WorkingDirectory = /var/swp
User = dotnetuser
Group = dotnetuser

[install]
```

I tried to execute the daemon using the systemctl status command: start netcore-console-swp.service

but I got:

> netcoreconsole-swp.service: Main process exited, code=exit

if I execute the app as `dotnet bot.dll` this working, what is wrong in my configuration?

What I did wrong?

Comment: `/var/bot/ swp.dll` this very different from what you've typed in your terminal no ?

Comment: sorry was a typo error, I tried different name, anyway the problem is the same

Comment: How do you know it *didn't* work? It's normal for "oneshot" services to run and then exit. Add logging to your app so you can cofirm where it exited.

Comment: Please fix your question to show what actually _was_ in your `ExecStart` setting, then.